# Adding location Marker/Pins on Google heatmap

Tags: web-mapping, google-maps-api, markers

I found a great free tool from Google for creating a heatmap at - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap

Is it possible for the above tool to have location coordinates shown as marker or pins as well?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what have you tried so far? what is not working?